# Count how many times the file has been opened

Tags: python

Ok so... I'm trying to make an discord bot as some of you know, and I want to organize the logs while they are created so... for example... when I open the bot file to run (draco.py) it creates an file called `1_logs` and when I close it keeps saved and when I open the file to the bot to run it makes the file `2_logs`

Is that possible? Ive tried creating another file that counts what log number is with `file.read()` and `file.write()`, but I didnt had any success...

Is that possible?

Comment: "Ive tried creating another file that counts what log number is" - that's exactly what you should do here. So, what's your question? (If it's "is that possible?", then, yes, it absolutely is).

Comment: The title seems wrong. You want to find the next file to be open, not count how many times a given file is open, right?

Comment: i want to count how mane tyimes it has been opened

Answer (score 0):

If you are keeping the log files in a folder, you can easily search through your folder using either os, sys or glob modules. Then you can sort them. 
But still what @ForceBru suggested is easier.

For example:

```
glob.glob('*_logs') # will give you all the log files you have.
```

Comment: Let's say you have a folder named: "Logs". In that folder you have log files named "1.log, 2.log, 3.log, 4.log".  If you run the code below you will have the list of all the files. glob.glob uses regex to list files. 

   ' from glob import glob
    glob.glob('Logs/*.log') '